# Transform dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in one format (summing up events' occurrences by UUID, events in separate rows) but would need it in a different format (events' occurrences in separate columns for each event).
How to, by using Python, transform it from:

| UUid | Event | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B32E7AA5B11A40AE | page XY opened | 121 |
| B32E7AA5B11A40AE | shopcart filled | 92 |
| B32E7AA5B11A40AE | purchase made | 23 |
| 2AEFB3AEA64140BE | page XY opened | 221 |
| 2AEFB3AEA64140BE | shopcart filled | 21 |
| A0DFAACDEB4D40C1 | page XY opened | 1345 |
| A0DFAACDEB4D40C1 | shopcart filled | 1323 |
| A0DFAACDEB4D40C1 | purchase made | 1321 |

To this:

| UUid | page XY opened | shopcart filled | purchase made |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B32E7AA5B11A40AE | 121 | 92 | 23 |
| 2AEFB3AEA64140BE | 221 | 23 | 0 |
| A0DFAACDEB4D40C1 | 1345 | 1323 | 1321 |

I don't know where to start.

Comment: use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Comment: Create a new DF with the columns you want. Iterate your original df and add the data for one UID to your new df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pivot()` and `fillna()`

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='UUid', columns='Event', values='sum').fillna(0)
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()

df_pivot
```

Output:

|  | UUid | page XY opened | purchase made | shopcart filled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2AEFB3AEA64140BE | 221 | 0 | 21 |
| 1 | A0DFAACDEB4D40C1 | 1345 | 1321 | 1323 |
| 2 | B32E7AA5B11A40AE | 121 | 23 | 92 |

Answer (score 1):

df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='sum', index='UUid', columns='Event', fill_value=0)

df = df.reset_index()